# Scrolling div & insert from bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add a scrolling bar when there is not enough space on a div.
Also, I would like to insert rows from bottom of this div.
I tried `overflow:auto` but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
var a=0;
$(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
               a++;
        $('#content').append('line'+a+'<br>');
             
 });
});
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  bottom: 1%;
  left: 2%;
   width: 40vw;
  height: 49vh;
  max-width: 260px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
   background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#content {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
   overflow: auto;
 }
#add{
  position:relative;
  top:270px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="content">
 
  </div>
  
</div>
<button id="add">add</button>
```

Comment: I add a JSFiddle: [enter link description here][1]
adding height or font-size doesn't work.
Overflow works if I remove the #content div, but in this way I can't have taxt from bottom


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/mcrhh7tu/

Comment: Looks like you got some answers already, but here’s a quick tip on making scrollable regions more accessible https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2016/02/short-note-on-improving-usability-of-scrollable-regions/

Answer (score 2):

Add **height:100%** in #content. **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/ynog7817/)**

```
#content{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You can also provide a down scroll for each new element. Test this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/0krc4nx3/)**

```
var a=0;
var content=$('#content');
$(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
            a++;
            content.append('line'+a+'<br>');
            content.scrollTop(content.height());
    });
});
```

Comment: overflow:scroll isn't right. it will display the scrolling bar even when is not needed

Comment: @mario I have updated my solution I think it does exactly what you wanted
look here: https://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/zyvswxu8/

Comment: I edited my answer so now you can also provide a down scroll for each new element. Test it: https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/0krc4nx3/

Comment: Add this in the js: $('#content').scrollTop($('#content').scrollTop($(document).height());

Look At my fiddle:  jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/zyvswxu8

Comment: @Vixed it works with max-height:100%; if I use height:100% it stard from top, not from bottom...i don't know why...:D thank you guys!

Comment: you must see my fiddle, it start from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

in `#content`
you should have the following:

```
 #content {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
   overflow: auto;
   max-height:49vh;
 }
```

If you want the scrolling bar to be down always, simply do in js:

```
var a=0;
$(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
               a++;
        $('#content').append('line'+a+'<br>');
        $('#content').scrollTop($(document).height());
    });
});
```

Here's a working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/zyvswxu8/2/)

Comment: Doesn't work nothing with height attribute in #content! I can't see text. Doesn't work with font-size also.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works! how can I do to keep the scrollbar down? i would see always the last line

Comment: Thanks both vixed and IsraGab :D

Answer (score 0):

Applying `overlflow-y: scroll` should've worked but instead made the scrollbars inert on both divs (never seen that before). I removed the outer div and changed the `#content div` `position: absolute` it works great now. As content grows, the scrollbar gets longer. If you want the box to expand as the content grows, use `position: relative`<del>I also changed the dynamic content from text lines to divs.</del>

```js
var a=0;
$(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
               a++;
        $('#content').append('line'+a+'<br/>');
             
 });
});
```

```css
#content {
  display: table-cell;
  position: absolute;
  /*Use relative if you want the box to expand with the content.*/
  /*position: relative;*/
  
  top: 1%;
  bottom: 1%;
  left: 2%;
  
  width: 40vw;
  max-width: 260px;
  height: 70vh;
  /*Use this if you want the box to strech to the edge */ 
  /*min-height:100%;*/

  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  bottom:0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }

#add {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">

  
</div>
<button id="add">add</button>
```